# get frequency based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

A snippet of my large dataframe that looks this way :

```
MARKERS.IN.HAPLOTYPES BASE           rs. alleles chrom       pos        GID marker   trial
                 1A.12    C S1A_494392059     C/G    1A 494392059 GID7173723      2 ES26-38
                 1A.13    C S1A_497201550     C/T    1A 497201550 GID7173723      0 ES26-38
                 1A.14    T S1A_499864157     C/T    1A 499864157 GID7173723      2 ES26-38
                 1B.10    A S1B_566171302     G/A    1B 566171302 GID7173723      0 ES26-38
                 1B.20    G S1B_642616640     A/G    1B 642616640 GID7173723      2 ES26-38
                 2B.10    A  S2B_24883552     A/G    2B  24883552 GID7173723      2 ES26-38
```

Here is a `dput` of it:

```
structure(list(MARKERS.IN.HAPLOTYPES = c("1A.12", "1A.13", "1A.14", 
"1B.10", "1B.20", "2B.10"), BASE = c("C", "C", "T", "A", "G", 
"A"), rs. = c("S1A_494392059", "S1A_497201550", "S1A_499864157", 
"S1B_566171302", "S1B_642616640", "S2B_24883552"), alleles = c("C/G", 
"C/T", "C/T", "G/A", "A/G", "A/G"), chrom = c("1A", "1A", "1A", 
"1B", "1B", "2B"), pos = c(494392059L, 497201550L, 499864157L, 
566171302L, 642616640L, 24883552L), GID = c("GID7173723", "GID7173723", 
"GID7173723", "GID7173723", "GID7173723", "GID7173723"), marker = c("2", 
 "0", "2", "0", "2", "2"), trial = c("ES26-38", "ES26-38", "ES26-38", 
 "ES26-38", "ES26-38", "ES26-38")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
 "data.frame")
```

There are 22 `unique` values for the columns `rs.` in the original dataframe and there are six `unique` values for the column `trial`. I would like to calculate the relative frequencies of the different values of column `marker` for each unique `rs.` and each unique `trial`. So for example, the first item of column `rs.` `S1A_494392059`would have the frequencies of column `marker` for trial `ES26-38` and so on, so forth. Please note that the column `marker` is a character vector and not numeric.

Comment: Maybe you can try `df %>%
 group_by(trial, marker, rs.) %>%
 tally()`.

Comment: Or just `df %>% add_count(rs., trial, marker)`. You can also tailor the `name` by the argument if you're using `dplyr 0.8` or above.

Comment: ah sorry. I mean the the relative frequency of the `marker` column

Comment: what you mean by tailoring the name by argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_count(rs., trial, name = "Total") %>%
  add_count(rs., trial, marker, name = "MarkerTotal") %>%
  mutate(RelativeFreq = round(MarkerTotal / Total, 2))
```

The `name` column in `add_count` is a new feature from `dplyr 0.8` onwards that allows you to decide on the name (previously would be `n` or `nn` by default). The above code won't work if you don't have the package up to date.

The relative frequencies in your example will be 1 everywhere though as it's not particularly complex.

This is what you could do if you'd like to get a summarised data frame (where the only columns left will be grouping `rs.`, `trial` and `RelativeFreq`):

```
df %>% 
  add_count(rs., trial, marker, name = "MarkerTotal") %>%
  group_by(rs., trial) %>%
  summarise(RelativeFreq = round(MarkerTotal / n(), 2))
```

Comment: nice thanks. I am trying to fetch form the summarised dataframe the column `base` with `semi_join` and `inner_join` but one the first doesnt work and the second expand the data into many other rows.

Comment: You're welcome! For the joins, you'll need to post and elaborate as I cannot think of something simple; best open a new topic with examples (best with `dput`).